# Differential equations and proof

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, differential

I have solved [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0ZsJH.png). But I don't know how to came up with the (1\2) beside m. I have tried I but I was unable to do that. Please help me in this.

Comment: Hi! what did you try?

Comment: I tried through multiplying the equation with dx/dt then. integrate it with respect to dt. But after doing all these things it gives me the form of previous equation from where I started.

Answer (score 0):

The trick is to just to realize that $\int x \dot{x}dt = \frac{x^2}{2} + C$ where $C$ is an integration constant (try integrating by parts with $u(t) = x(t)$ and $v(t) = \dot{x} dt$ if you have troubles with it). The same is true if we change $x \mapsto \dot{x}$ and $\dot{x} \mapsto \ddot{x}$. So when you multiply by $\frac{dx}{dt}$ and the integrate, you are just creating two integrals of the same functional form:
$$
\begin{aligned}
&\int \dot{x} \ddot{x} dt + \omega^2\int x \dot{x} dt = 0 \\ 
&\iff \frac{1}{2} \left( \frac{dx}{dt} \right) ^2 + C_1 + \omega^2 \left( \frac{1}{2}x^2 + C_2 \right) = 0
\end{aligned}
$$

You get to the result just by using the fact that $\omega^2 = \frac{k}{m}$, multiplying by $m$ and summing all the corresponding constants to $E$.

I hope it helps :)

Comment: ∫xx˙dt=1\2(x^2)+c. how can you write this. Can you explain in please??

Comment: It's just a basic integration fact if you don't see it directly you could try to use integration by parts (as written in the answer) or take a look at [wolfram alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=x%28t%29+x%27%28t%29+dt) to convince yourself or at [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integration_by_substitution). If my answer helped you please consider accepting it.

Comment: Yeah. That helped. Can you please say where to find these types of differential equation solves or theory. I mean which book?

Comment: There are lots of good books on the subject, try looking at [1](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/400806/differential-equations-reference-request) and [2](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1249939/ordinary-differential-equations-self-study-reference-request).

Comment: But if we put E on the left side and then take it on the right side then in it will -E. But the proof says it will be E. How?

Comment: the sign of the constant is unimportant in this case; you can sum up all constants on the left and name them $E_0$ then move $E_0$ to the right and name it $E = -E_0$ it will be just the same.